# How to disable clear text authentication RabbitMQ

Tags: docker, ssl, openssl, rabbitmq

am using the RabbitMQ docker from https://hub.docker.com/_/rabbitmq.

I recently received a warning (which I must fix) saying "The remote host is running a service that allows cleartext authentication". The RabbitmQ docker uses port 5672 (AMQP) and this causes the warning.

How/What do I define in the configuration passed to the docker to achieve this? I am using the defaults of the docker and, unfortunately, I am not too familiar with RabbitMQ or with certificates so I require detailed explanation.

My "service" doesn't even define a password for RabbitMQ and uses defaults.

Comment: Do not use the port **5672** on the rabbitmq server and follow the instructions on 

https://www.rabbitmq.com/ssl.html

to enable SSL on the rabbitmq server then use **5671** to access amqp services using tls.